# Python dynamically increment a dictionary on loop issue

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to do something like below. Where if the "If statement" on a loop criteria matches I want to do an increment using one of the parameters from the "If" statement.

```
value = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
data = {'value': 3, 'foo': 'foo'}
for value in value:
    if (int(data['value']) == value and data['foo'] == 'foo'):
        findings_score[value] =  findings_score[value] + 1
```

I'm trying to do this on python and I get an error since the values - "findings_score[value]"` need to be initialized. I can do that by individually initialing the findings_score[value] dict, but I want to understand the best approach here.

`Error - NameError: global name 'findings_score[value]' is not defined

Comment: I don't see a mention of `findings_rec_risk_score` in your code... is it the same as `findings_score`? If so, you should edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: Your iterating variable is the same name as the iterable (`value`), and I don't see anything named `findings_rec_risk_score`.

Comment: Uh, could you please check your whitespacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), initialising the dict outside the loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict
findings_score = defaultdict(int)
values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

for value in values:
    if int(data['value']) == value and data['foo'] == 'foo':
        findings_score[value] += 1
```

Using a normal dict you could use dict.setdefault or dict.get:

```
findings_score = {}
values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

for value in values:
    if int(data['value']) == value and data['foo'] == 'foo':
        findings_score[value] = findings_score.get(value, 0) + 1

findings_score = {}
values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

for value in values:
    if int(data['value']) == value and data['foo'] == 'foo':
        findings_score.setdefault(value, 0)
        findings_score[value] += 1
```

If you want all the elements in values to be in the output you can use dict.fromkeys:

```
 findings_score = dict.fromkeys(values,0)
 for value in values:
     if int(data['value']) == value and data['foo'] == 'foo':
        findings_score[value] += 1
```

Comment: @user4723845, no prob, you could use a normal dict with dict.setdefault or dict.get but a defautdict is the most efficient

Comment: But now, I'm not able to reference values: For Example print findings_score[2]

Comment: @user4723845, not sure what you mean, the keys are each value from values. They only get added if your if statement evaluates to True though so don't expect them all. In you example only `3` would get added

Comment: I was doing something wrong. Defaultdict is the answer to my query :)

Comment: @user4723845, well you have a few options now anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
findings_score = {}

data = {'value': 3, 'foo': 'foo'}

for value in values:
    if (int(data['value']) == value and data['foo'] == 'foo'):
        if value in findings_score:
            findings_score[value] =  findings_score[value] + 1
        else:
            findings_score[value] = 1
```